# ASP Global Navigation Bar bad links across subfolders

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to create a global navigation bar in an ASP.NET master page which links to pages across different folders, however once I navigate to a page within a sub-folder the links obviously don't work. How do I create links which start always start from the root directory?

For example on a page in the root folder the link could be

```
mysite.com/folder1/default.aspx
```

But once on that page the link turns into

```
mysite.com/folder1/folder1/default.aspx
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start links from the route, you use tilde `~`.  So, the links would be 
`~/folder1/default.aspx` and `~/folder1/folder1/default.aspx`

Comment: Are there any other changes I need to make because that is giving me the following URL: http://localhost:54425/~Folder1/Default.aspx

Comment: are these standard links? or `asp:Hyperlink` ? if standard, you will need `runat="server"`

Comment: Ahhh sucess! Thanks christiandev, I just needed to add runat="server"